# Can't connect to an AWS MySQL RDS using JDBC when site is deployed to elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I created a MySQL DB on amazon running on the same account as my tomcat server, it built and is running correctly but can't connect to the database.

I can access the remote database running the site using tomcat on my computer, and I can access the db through MySQL workbench, but when I deploy and run it I get a 500 whenever the site tries to access the database.

I opened up my security on this database to accept any connection and port(lol), and I checked if the mysql java connector.jar in the WEB-INF/libs file is the latest version. I even tried setting the JDBC connection string to localhost to see if it would pick it up, but no luck.

I think I'm missing something, can anyone think of any reason my website's JDBC can access the remote database server from my machine but not from the amazon tomcat server?

Also, this is a student project I'm building.

Hope this description makes sense, maybe someone can think of something I haven't tried:)

Comment: Examine the logs for the cause.

Comment: The logs say there is a NullPointerException, what I expected since it's not making a connection. I suspect it's something to do with configuration on the aws server. Like it's being blocked by a firewall or something. Does that make sense?

Comment: your tomcat server is on an EC2? Or a Beanstalk instance? Show us the output of `telnet [db]:[db ip]` and take a screenshot showing the security group rules of the DB.